# Queue move item back to the end

Tags: c#, queue

I have a `System.Collection.Generic.Queue<int>` with following sample code

```
Queue<int> iq = new Queue<int>();
iq.Enqueue(1); // 1
iq.Enqueue(2); // 1 2
iq.Enqueue(3); // 1 2 3

//move 1 to the end of the line here

int i = iq.Dequeue(); // 2 3
```

I want to *move* the value (access **by value**) `1` back to the end of the line so that the result is `2` and `1` would be the last dequeueable value.

Any idea? Is there something like `iq.MoveToLast(1)` ?

Comment: Dequeue, Enqueue, done. Or does it have to be atomic?

Comment: @Fildor I need access by value. One requirement could also be to move `2` back

Comment: Ok. That's a different story. You then need a collection with access by index.

Comment: It seems you want `List<int>` instead of `Queue<int>`: `int index = id.IndexOf(2); if (index >= 0) {id.RemoveAt(index); id.Add(2);}`

Comment: I second the suggestion to use `List<int>`. You can still use it "Queue-Like": `Add` Appends to the end, so that equals `Enqueue` and you can `Remove(0)` which removes the List's head, so it acts like `Dequeue` + you have indexed acces.

Comment: If you want to keep Enqueue and Dequeue as "API" , you can wrap a List<int> and implement the methods accordingly. Then you could add a "MoveToEnd" method.

Comment: Mind: All of the suggested solutions are not thread-safe. Do you need thread-safety?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to `Remove` / `Add` item by its *value*, you can use `List<T>` instead of `Queue<T>`:

```
List<int> id = ...

int itemToMove = 2;

int index = id.IndexOf(itemToMove);

// If we have item found we should put it at the end
if (index >= 0) {
  id.Add(id[index]);
  id.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

If you *have to use* `Queue<T>` you can create a *temporal* `List<T>`:

```
  Queue<int> iq = ...

  int itemToMove = 2;

  // Create temporal list
  var list = iq.ToList();

  // process items in it
  int index = list.IndexOf(itemToMove);

  if (index >= 0) {
    list.Add(list[index]);
    list.RemoveAt(index);
  }

  // enqueue items back into queue in the desired order
  iq.Clear();

  foreach (var item in list)
    iq.Enqueue(item);
```

Finally, you can implement an *extension method*:

```
  public static partial class QueueExtensions {
    public static void MoveToLast<T>(this Queue<int> queue, T itemToMove) {
      if (null == queue)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queue)); 

      var list = queue.ToList();

      int index = list.IndexOf(itemToMove);

      if (index < 0)
        return; // Nothing to do

      list.Add(list[index]);
      list.RemoveAt(index);

      queue.Clear();

      foreach (var item in list)
        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
  }
```

Then you can put

```
 iq.MoveToLast(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue());
```

You can't `Remove` elements from `Queue` by using methods other than `Dequeue`.

Comment: I need access by value. One requirement could also be to move 2 back - so `Enqueue/Dequeue` doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which just manipulates the queue:

```
public static void MoveElementToBack<T>(Queue<T> queue, T elementToMove)
{
    T item = default;
    bool found = false;

    for (int i = 0, n = queue.Count; i < n; ++i)
    {
        var current = queue.Dequeue();

        if (!found && current.Equals(elementToMove))
        {
            item  = current;
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            queue.Enqueue(current);
        }
    }

    if (found)
        queue.Enqueue(item);
}
```

This is always an `O(N)` operation, but it only makes one pass through the queue.